# imbalanced_learn sorts labels

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to use imbalanced_learn RandomUnderSampler, but whenever I execute it, it sorts the label, making the data useless. Y contains ints, either 1 or 0. This is the code:

```
X, Y = df.iloc[:, 1:], df.iloc[:, 0]

X_res, Y_res = RandomUnderSampler().fit_sample(X, Y)

print(Y_res)
```

Printing Y gives me 0       1
     0
     0
      0
    1
    1
      1
      1
       0
       1
0

-> random as expected.

While printing Y_res gives me 0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0

While the last ones are  1 1 1 1 1  1 1...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thats the expected behaviour. You can shuffle them easily yourself. Like when you send it to `train_test_split` it will be shuffled automatically

Comment: Thanks for that method, I always splitted and shuffled it by writing my own code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. Return a subset of data set with equal proportions of 2 classes. If your initial data set had a skew, say 90:10::1:0, Under-sampled X_res,Y_res are part of data set where 1:0 are close to 50:50. Now you can shuffle split X_res,Y_res in train,test,validate as per your requirement